# Is it possible to remove the top padding for input fields in Safari?

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

On Safari 16.6 and lower, if you have an HTML `input` field that has a font-size larger than the height of the input, the value in the input will have padding above the value that cannot be removed or overridden, but the placeholder will have the expected alignment that matches other browsers

This happens on Safari 16.6 and lower on MacOS, or on iOS/iPad OS 16 and lower. Safari 17 and iOS 17 both behave the same as all versions of Chrome do

This issue only occurs with the value in the input, but using placeholder does not have the same issue. Once typing in the field with the placeholder, it has the same alignment issue

HTML

```
<input value="Test">
<input placeholder="Test">
```

CSS:

```
input {
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

JSFiddle to reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/4bq91t6k/

Result on Safari 16.6:
[incorrectly aligned input in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FaMI.png)

Result on Chrome, or Safari 17:
[correctly aligned input in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAiRg.png)

I tried removing the padding/margin that was added by the browser with no changes. Setting line-height does not help

Tried setting `input::-webkit-input-placeholder{ padding-top: 0px; }` with no change either

Comment: Life is too short to worry about old web browsers.

Comment: @BrettDonald - oh that this were so! There may be millions of users of an application on devices that will last years more but will never be able to upgrade iOS even if they were prepared to (me at the moment for a start).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue by placing the input in a div, and using a flex-box to center the input in the div, regardless of the height of the input. The only downside to this solution is that the cursor will show outside the confines of the div which may not work for everyone

HTML:

```
<div class="text-input">
  <input value="Test">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text-input input {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0px;
  width: 190px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.text-input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 190px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/804aLkr9/